# Replace just a string's portion in a list from a dictionary

Tags: python

I am struggling when trying to replace string's portions from a list, using a dictionary. I have a list with network IPs and subnet masks:

```
10.10.1.20/255.255.255.0
40.50.1.10/255.255.255.224
18.1.14.50/255.255.255.128
18.1.28.50/255.255.255.248
```

My idea is to create a dictionary to replace the subnet masks into prefix masks, for example:

```
10.10.1.20/24
40.50.1.10/27
18.1.14.50/25
18.1.28.50/29
```

I am getting these IPs after using a small code to get IPs from a huge document, and my current code looks like this:

```
dict = {'255.255.255.0':'24','255.255.255.255':'32'}  #I will add here all subnet masks that I need.

with open(r'C:\Users\robert\Subnets.txt') as file:
  contents = file.read().split('\n')
  subnet = []
  for ele in contents:
    if ele.__contains__('IP/Netmask'):
        subnet.append(ele.split(':')[1])


print(subnet)     #This works fine and I can get all the IPs/Mask from the document in this format: 10.10.1.20/255.255.255.0

subnet[:]=[dict.get(e,'') for e in subnet]

print(subnet)     #This does not print anything, because I do not know how to replace just a portion of the string
```

Comment: could you also add sample date from `Subnets.txt`?

Comment: show us some example of txt file

Comment: Add an example of the txt file so we can recreate code in our environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
my_dict = {'255.255.255.0':'24','255.255.255.255':'32'}
subnet = [item.split('/')[0]+'/'+my_dict.get(item.split('/')[1], '') for item in subnet]
```

This will also replace your subnet masks with empty strings if a corresponding prefix mask is not present in the dictionary.

Also **dict** is a keyword in python dont use it as variable names.

Comment: Thanks, it has workied fine. Sorry for such basic questions but I am a noob in python and did not found how to fix this after checking for a while.

Comment: @Debon54 no problem, don't know why your question was downvoted, you have provided all details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code mentioned below for substituting subnet masks:

```
[e.split("/")[0]+dict[e.split("/")[1]] for e in subnet]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {'255.255.255.0':'24','255.255.255.255':'32'}  #I will add here all subnet masks that I need.

with open(r'C:\Users\robert\Subnets.txt') as file:
  contents = file.read().split('\n')
  subnet = []
  for ele in contents:
    if ele.__contains__('IP/Netmask'):
        subnet.append(ele.split(':')[1])


print(subnet)     #This works fine and I can get all the IPs/Mask from the document in this format: 10.10.1.20/255.255.255.0
subnet1 = []
for ip in subnet:
   split = ip.split('/')//Split by the /
   part1 = split[0]//The first part
   part2 = split[1]//The second part which we will replace
   part2 = dictionary[part2]//Replacing part 2 with its counter part
   subnet1.append(part1+'/'+part2)

print(subnet1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you're making a second subnet list from a previous one with a for.

You can do something like that to save time.

```
dico = {'255.255.255.0':'24','255.255.255.255':'32'}
file = """10.10.1.20/255.255.255.0
40.50.1.10/255.255.255.255"""

contents = file.split('\n')
subnet = [e.split("/")[0] + "/" + dico.get(e.split("/")[1]) for e in contents]
print(subnet)
```

Result :

```
['10.10.1.20/24', '40.50.1.10/32']
```

I'm not sure it's  what your looking for but you can get the string you want where you want using the good slice.